# Why input and unput lex functions can not be redefined via #undef?

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I am executing an example of the book "Lex & Yacc". The example redefined input and unput lex functions to handle parsing from command line arguments instead of using the standard input.

The source code has been copied from the book almost verbatim, adapting it to ANSI C. But it seems that I can not redefine the functions.

```
%{
#undef input
#undef unput

int input(void);
void unput(int ch);

/* LEXICON RELATED VARIABLES */
unsigned verbose;
char *prog_name;

/* PARSING RELATED VARIABLES */
char **targv;
char **arglim;
static unsigned offset = 0 ;

%}

%%

-h              |
"-?"            |
-help           {
                        printf("usage is: %s [ -help | -h | -? ] [ -verbose | -v ] [ (-file | -f) filename ]\n", prog_name);
                }

-v              |
-verbose        {
                        printf("verbose mode is on\n"); verbose=1;
                }

.               ;


%%

int input(void) {

        char c;

        if(targv >= arglim)
                return(0);      /* EOF */

        if((c = targv[0][offset++]) != '\0')
                return(c);

        targv++;
        offset = 0;
        return(' ');

}

void unput(int ch) {

        /* AT&T lex sometimes puts back the EOF! */
        if(ch == '\0')
                return; /* ignore, can't put back EOF */

        if(offset) {    /* back up in current arg */
                offset--;
                return;
        }
        targv--;        /* back to previous arg */
        offset = strlen(*targv);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        prog_name = *argv;
        targv = argv+1;
        arglim = argv+argc;
        yylex();
        return 0;

}
```

However when trying to compile and link, I get the following errors. I am not fully understanding why I am getting the errors, and why the source code is no longer valid in current lex implementations.

```
$ lex test.l; cc lex.yy.c -ll -o test
lex.yy.c:545:12: error: static declaration of 'input' follows non-static declaration
static int input ( void );
           ^
test.l:5:5: note: previous declaration is here
int input(void);
    ^
lex.yy.c:1154:16: error: static declaration of 'input' follows non-static declaration
    static int input  (void)
               ^
test.l:5:5: note: previous declaration is here
int input(void);
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Because they are no longer `#define`s but actual functions. IOW your book is obsolete.

Comment: I understand. What would be the current/not obsolete way to redefine input and unput in (f)lex? What is the reason for defines having been used in the past? Efficiency to avoid a function call?

Comment: Can you show the declarations that were generated?